# sublime: get elixir results in an external terminal

Tags: sublimetext3, elixir

I use `sublime` to build `elixir` files, but the results are shown in the native console of the sublime.

I wonder if there is a way to get the results in an external window, like in Geany IDE.

I found several similar questions about python, but didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved:**

This is what I had to do:

```
{
"cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"elixir $file;echo;echo Press return to continue; read line\"'"],"shell": true
}
```